# Can I reload php.ini without stopping and starting IIS?

Tags: php, iis

I have a few websites running with IIS 10 that use the same `php.ini`, and I now changed a value in the `php.ini` file which cannot be set via the `ini_set()` method in PHP.

Is there any way to reload the `php.ini` for one of the websites without stopping and starting the entire server? Restarting the website itself does not work.

I don't want to stop operation for users who might be using the other websites now

Comment: Hi, thank you, that's the same as if I did "stop" and "start" via the GUI right? So I guess there is no escape from a quick restart

Comment: It's enough to restart the Application Pool associated with the specific site.

Comment: You don't have to restart IIS, just the application pool, as @harrymc notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to restart IIS.

It's enough to restart the Application Pool associated with the specific site.

Comment: Thank you! that worked!